# What does psutil.cpu_percent() return? Is it the highest or lowest or average cpu usage during the time it is monitored?

Tags: python, cpu-usage, psutil

I am monitoring the cpu usage of a code run. When I call cpu_percent method, what does the method return during the time frame of 2 calls of psutil.cpu_percent?- average, highest peak or lowest peak